# How to create mock form data to perform unit testing on a Javascript controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

I have a controller that performs the following function which looks like this:

```
angular.module('events').controller('EventsController', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$location', 'Authentication', 'Events',
function($scope, $stateParams, $location, Authentication, Events) { 

//initialize some stuff

$scope.create = function() {
        // Create new Event object
        var event = new Events ({
            name: this.name,
            details: this.details,
            date: this.date,
            time: this.time,
            pointValue: this.pointValue,
            studentIDs: this.studentIDs
        });

        // Redirect after save
        event.$save(function(response) {
            $location.path('events/' + response._id);

            // Clear form fields
            $scope.name = '';
            $scope.details = '';
        }, function(errorResponse) {
            $scope.error = errorResponse.data.message;
        });
    };

//rest of the controllers functions go below
};
```

I am in the process of writing unit tests for this controller, however, I do not know how to inject a sample Event into this function or what to compare the function's output to in the tests. I am very new at Javascript and would appreciate all the help I can get